# Finding number position in ranges

Tags: numbers, range

I am writing a function that has to find the position of a given number within numerical ranges, the range is a variable within the code, for now lets say the range is `4` so the ranges will look like the following:
`[ 0-3 ]
[ 4-7 ]
[ 8-11 ]
[ 12-15 ]
[ 16-19 ]
[ 20-23 ]
[ 24-27 ]`

What i would like to achieve is to find the range where a given number belongs to, in the quickest way possibly,as this operation is performed over million of events.
So what i have wrote so far, and it works fine, is the following:
`public String findRange(int range,int number2bFound)
    {
      int base = 0;
      if (number2bFound == 0)
        number2bFound = 1.0;
      int higher = 0;
      while (base <= number2bFound)
      {
        higher = base + (range - 1);
        if ((base <= number2bFound) && (higher >= number2bFound))
          return base + "-" + higher;
        base += range;
      }
      return null;
    }`

So as i said this works, but i am sure this can be done implemented more efficiently, by only using the value of `number2bFonud` and the `range` and excluding the very expensive loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if all the ranges have the same size and it start from 0, a simple division will do, additionally you can find the position in the sub-range with a modulo operation.

The procedure is simple, find the integer division of your number `n` against yours range size and that will give you in which sub-range it belong, to find the position inside the sub-range find the modulo of your number again against the range size

here is a example python

```
def find_position(n,size):
    return (n//size, n%size)
```

with range of size 4

```
>>> test=[ [0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9,10,11], [12,13,14,15], [16,17,18,19], [20,21,22,23] ]
>>> find_position(6,4)
(1, 2)
>>> test[1][2]
6
>>> find_position(11,4)
(2, 3)
>>> test[2][3]
11
>>>
```

with range 5

```
>>> test=[ [0,1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8,9] ,[10,11,12,13,14],[15,16,17,18,19],  [20,21,22,23,24] ]
>>> find_position(11,5)
(2, 1)
>>> test[2][1]
11
>>>
```

The procedure is a follow, let `Size` be the size of each sub-range and `n` the number you wan to locate, then you only need to the be the take the number n you want to find.

translate that to java should be very simple, excuse if my is a little rusty but is something like this I think

```
public String findRange(int range,int number2bFound){
    int sub_ran_pos, pos;
    sub_ran_pos = (int) number2bFound/range;    //or however the integer division is in java
    pos = number2bFound % range;                //or however the modulo operation it is in java
    return sub_ran_pos + "-" + pos;             //or the appropriate return type, for this
}
```

(I don't remember, but if java is 1-index then you need to add 1 to each number to get right result)